# Streaming large files using TinyTDS/FreeTDS

Tags: ruby, freetds, tiny-tds

When I run a simple select on a row, I only get about 64K of data for BLOB columns. I'd like to get all of it, streaming would be preferable of course to avoid memory problems.

Comment: Looks like this may help out:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260626(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: Show us an example of your code, with a minimal example of your schema showing the field in question. Streaming data to what, a web client? There's a lot of missing detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good morning,

IIRC, FreeTDS defaults to a 64K limit for text size. In your `freetds.conf` try changing this setting:

```
text size = 64512
```

to something like this:

```
text size = 4194304
```

The maximum size of a text field in SQL Server, as an example, is 2,147,483,647 bytes.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't able to make this change easily, but this is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I had to to use `SUBSTRING(column_name, start, length) AS chunk` in order to get what I wanted. The length I kept under 64KB and ran the query multiple times, increasing the start value and saving the file. It's less efficient as far as the multiple queries go, but it keeps the memory low.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, we you trying to conserve memory on the SQL side or the Ruby side? Or both?

Comment: Just the Ruby side. I have no control over the SQL server in this instance.